# route your blog from xyz.com/blog/ to abc.com/blog/

Tags: domain, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect

My WordPress website domain name was abc.com (let's say) now due to a new partnership agreement the domain name is changing to WordPress xyz.com (let's say).

I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816284/redirect-all-urls-exactly-just-change-domain-name/19816343#19816343 but it is not working for me.

`DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`
[image]

Note: The Old domain abc.com is expired means I purchased it from GoDaddy but didn't renew it because I purchased a new domain.

So the purpose of setting up 301 is so that whatever blogs or important articles were shared in the past if the user clicks on them then users can reach to correct blog/article.

How can I 301 all the pages to the new domain so that I don't lose ranking?

Comment: Provide the config that did not work for you, so someone can check what you did wrong.

Comment: Added the `.htaccess` file that I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to own the old domain in order to set up the redirects to new domain.

If you have let your old domain expire, it no longer exists (no DNS records exist) or somebody has registered it and has set up his own DNS records there. In this case it is not possible to have any redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily perform the task of routing your blog from the old domain (abc.com/blog/) to the new domain (xyz.com/blog/) using Cloudflare by leveraging its Page Rules feature.

Log In to Your Cloudflare Dashboard: Log in to your Cloudflare account.

Access Page Rules: In your Cloudflare dashboard, go to the "Page Rules" section in your old domain.

Create a Page Rule for Old URLs:

Click on "Create Page Rule."

In the "If the URL matches" field, enter `https://example.com/blog/*` to match all URLs under your old domain's /blog/ path.

Click on "Add a Setting" and choose "Forwarding URL" from the dropdown.

Select "301 - Permanent Redirect" as the type.

In the "Destination URL" field, enter `https://example2.com/blog/$1` (this captures the wildcard part of the old URL and appends it to the new URL).

Click "Save and Deploy."

If you are redirecting whole domain then remove "/blog" from the both urls.